# Rotating External Credential Principal

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, namedcredentials, externalcredentials, principal

I am looking to call an external API from Salesforce using AWS Signature v4. The external API is using AWS API Gateway with IAM authorization enabled. I have created an access key for an IAM user and will automatically rotate the key every 90 days.

As part of the automatic key rotation, I would like to add a new access key to the Principals of the External Credential and delete the outdated key.

Is there a Salesforce API that would let me add and delete Principals on an External Credential?

Comment: For a single principal - you want [ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.updateCredential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_updateCredential_4).

Comment: Thank you @identigral.

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish this? We are facing a similar problem where we need to update the client secret of a principal every week, we are currently using legacy named credentials with OAuth providers, and rotating is deploying a custom metadata, but with external credentials, I cannot find any clarifying documentation.